# How to remove duplicate words in a cell only if longer than a certain number of characters

Tags: google-sheets

I need to remove a duplicate text in a cell but only if it is longer than 4 characters.

I have this formula that only works for any types of duplicate words:

```
=join(" ",unique(transpose(split(A1,", "))))
```

In this case, if a cell contains:

```
W3-X500 Samsung Galaxy W3-X500 5 inches and 5 different colors
```

It returns me:

```
W3-X500 Samsung Galaxy 5 inches and different colors
```

I will lose the second `5` character that instead I need.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure someone will come up with something shorter and simpler than this, but meanwhile

```
=ArrayFormula(substitute(join(" ",unique(if(len(transpose(split(A1,", ")))<=4,
transpose(split(A1,", "))&rept("*",row(indirect("1:"&counta(split(A1,", "))))),transpose(split(A1,", "))))),"*",""))
```

The idea is that if a word has less than five letters, put some stars on the end of it, otherwise leave it as it is. Then use unique, join together and finally get rid of the stars.

[image]

If a star can occur in the string, you can use some other character instead.

**EDIT**

This removes one of the transposes but Unique requires a column so still left with two:

```
=ArrayFormula(substitute(join(" ",unique(transpose(if(len(split(A1,", "))<=4,
split(A1,", ")&rept("*",transpose(row(indirect("1:"&counta(split(A1,", ")))))),split(A1,", "))))),"*",""))
```

**EDIT 2**

Both of the above can be further simplified:

```
=ArrayFormula(substitute(join(" ",unique(transpose(split(A1,", "))&if(len(transpose(split(A1,", ")))<=4,
rept("*",row(indirect("1:"&counta(split(A1,", "))))),""))),"*",""))
```

or

```
=ArrayFormula(substitute(join(" ",unique(transpose(split(A1,", ")&if(len(split(A1,", "))<=4,
rept("*",transpose(row(indirect("1:"&counta(split(A1,", ")))))),"")))),"*",""))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=REGEXREPLACE(ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" ", 
 UNIQUE(IF(LEN((SPLIT(B1, ", "))), 
        IF(LEN((SPLIT(B1, ", ")))>4, 
               (SPLIT(B1, ", ")), 
        IF(LEN((SPLIT(B1, ", ")))<=4, 
               (SPLIT(B1, ", "))&
 "ᅇ"&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(SIGN(ROW($A:$A))*1041, 1071))&
      CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(SIGN(ROW($A:$A))*1041, 1071))&
      CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(SIGN(ROW($A:$A))*1041, 1071))&"ᅇ", )), )))), 
 "\ᅇ([Б-Я]+)\ᅇ", "")
```

[image: 0]